# How to put every item in a list together in a string without spaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Doing an encryption project for school, and I have reached an point where I now put the encrypted message together as a string for the user to see.
Here's the list:

```
 ['p', '.', ',', '$', '!', '.', '#', '8', ' ', '.', '-', '"',
 '$', ' ', '3', '.', '+', '#', ' ', ',', '$', ' ', '3', "'", '$',
 ' ', '6', '.', '1', '+', '#', ' ', '(', '2', ' ', '&', '.',
 '-', '-', '~', ' ', '1', '.', '+', '+', ' ', ',', '$']
```

I'd like to print it (or at least store as a variable) as:
p.,$!.#8  .-"$  3.+#       etc... This includes the spaces.

Comment: `reduce(operator.add,msg_array)` ... seriously this is something you should probably talk to your classmates or professor about

Comment: Did you hear about the "join" command?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Bad idea - quadratic runtime. `''.join` is much better.

Answer (score 2):

just use join function

```
x = ['p', '.', ',', '$', '!', '.', '#', '8', ' ', '.', '-', '"',
 '$', ' ', '3', '.', '+', '#', ' ', ',', '$', ' ', '3', "'", '$',
 ' ', '6', '.', '1', '+', '#', ' ', '(', '2', ' ', '&', '.',
 '-', '-', '~', ' ', '1', '.', '+', '+', ' ', ',', '$']
value = "".join(x)
print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['p', '.', ',', '$', '!', '.', '#', '8', ' ', '.', '-', '"',
'$', ' ', '3', '.', '+', '#', ' ', ',', '$', ' ', '3', "'", '$',
' ', '6', '.', '1', '+', '#', ' ', '(', '2', ' ', '&', '.',
'-', '-', '~', ' ', '1', '.', '+', '+', ' ', ',', '$']
''.join(a) # with space
p.,$!.#8 .-"$ 3.+# ,$ 3\'$ 6.1+# (2 &.--~ 1.++ ,$

''.join([i for i in a if i.strip()]) # without space
p.,$!.#8.-"$3.+#,$3\'$6.1+#(2&.--~1.++,$
```